# Method .pivot_table() returns innumerable NaN unexpectedly

Tags: pivot-table, nan

I am pivoting several data frames. Some are pivoted correctly. Others are not.
I have 5 frames with same structure (acquired data from PLC, basically timestamps, variable name and corresponding value):

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hadyf.png)

```
((85247, 5), (255737, 5), (255734, 5), (574065, 5), (567587, 5))
```

The structure of the pivoted frame has timestamp as index and columns with values (ID and quality are dropped before pivoting).

Out of 5 data frames, 3 are pivoted correctly and 2 are filled with way too many NaN values.

```
(85247, 1), (85258, 3), (85258, 3), (85542, 84), (85216, 13)
```

The code is this one:

```
df_WATER['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_WATER['TIMESTAMP'], errors='ignore')
df_HSD['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_HSD['TIMESTAMP'], errors='ignore')
df_HSCPLC3['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_HSCPLC3['TIMESTAMP'], errors='ignore')
df_HSCPLC2ACT['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_HSCPLC2ACT['TIMESTAMP'], errors='ignore')
df_FURNACE['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_FURNACE['TIMESTAMP'], errors='ignore')

df_WATER = df_WATER.pivot_table(index='TIMESTAMP', columns='NAME', values='VALUE')
df_HSD = df_HSD.pivot_table(index='TIMESTAMP', columns='NAME', values='VALUE')
df_HSCPLC3 = df_HSCPLC3.pivot_table(index='TIMESTAMP', columns='NAME', values='VALUE')
df_HSCPLC2ACT = df_HSCPLC2ACT.pivot_table(index='TIMESTAMP', columns='NAME', values='VALUE')
df_FURNACE = df_FURNACE.pivot_table(index='TIMESTAMP', columns='NAME', values='VALUE')
```

It happens with the data frames whose number of columns exceeds 10 ((85542, 84), (85216, 13)). I wonder this may be a limit of this function.

```
TIMESTAMP                                                  
2022-11-18 20:00:00.224                              NaN   
2022-11-18 20:00:00.731                              NaN   
2022-11-18 20:00:01.240                              NaN   
2022-11-18 20:00:01.751                              NaN   
2022-11-18 20:00:02.259                              NaN   
...                                                  ...   
2022-11-19 07:59:57.906                              NaN   
2022-11-19 07:59:58.411                              NaN   
2022-11-19 07:59:58.920                              NaN   
2022-11-19 07:59:59.420                              NaN   
2022-11-19 07:59:59.927                              NaN
```